# How to get back to main() in C?

Tags: c, function, menu, switch-statement

My program's structure is like this:
main function has a menu (switch) between two other functions.
One of them is just a calculation and when it ends it goes back to this (main) menu.
Which is exactly what I want now (earlier I wanted to end the program after calculation and I had `exit(0);` in all cases.
But the other function is tricky because it starts another function (menu) and there are two options of calculations. One of them also has another switch.

The problem is when I edited codes which look like this by removing exit(0);

```
case 'H':
      rhdp(0,n_hdp0, fw_vystup);
      vyprazdni_buffer(); //buffer clearing
      exit(0);
      break;
```

It only works for the simple calculation but deeper parts of the program only go one step back...
Any possible solutions? Thanks in advance.

---

here is more of a code

```
void nhdp_menu(float cislo, FILE **fw_vystup)
{
    char c;
    float y, n_hdp0 = 0.0f, n_hdp1 = 0.0f;
    do {
        printf("Zadejte nominalni hruby domaci produkt daneho roku: ");

     zadani_cisla(&cislo);
     n_hdp1 = cislo;
    } while (n_hdp1 <= 0);
    do {
        printf("Zadejte nominalni hruby domaci produkt predesleho roku: ");
     zadani_cisla(&cislo);
     n_hdp0 = cislo;
    } while (n_hdp0 <= 0);
    y = (n_hdp1 - n_hdp0) / n_hdp0 * 100;
    printf("Tempo rustu nominalniho HDP je %f procent.\n", y);
    zapis(fw_vystup, "Nominalni HDP0 = %f ; Nominalni HDP1 = %f ; Tempo rustu nominalniho HDP je %f procent.\n", n_hdp0, n_hdp1, y);

    do {
        printf("Dodatecne muzete take zjistit tempo rustu REALNEHO HDP:\n");
        printf("Pokud znate deflator HDP v danem roce - zadejte D.\n");
        printf("Pokud znate primo realne HDP v danem roce - zadejte H.\n");
        vyprazdni_buffer();
        scanf("%c", &c);

        switch (c) {                                //this is the last (deepest) switch
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                rhdp_ipd(0, n_hdp0, n_hdp1, fw_vystup);
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                //exit(0);
                break;
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                rhdp(0,n_hdp0, fw_vystup);
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                //exit(0);
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                printf("Konec programu.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Neznama volba.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (c != 'k' && c != 'K');
    return;
}

void tempo_menu(n_hdp0)
{
    FILE *fw_vystup;
    char c;

    do {
        printf("Vyberte si, v jakych cenach chcete HDP uvadet.\nPro nominalni zadejte N.\nPro realne zadejte R.\n");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        vyprazdni_buffer();
        switch (c) {
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                nhdp_menu(0, &fw_vystup);  //this here is starting another menu
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                //exit(0);
                break;
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
                rhdp(0, 0, &fw_vystup);
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                //exit(0);
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                printf("Konec programu.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Neznama volba.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (c != 'k' && c != 'K');

    return;
}


int main(void)
{
    char c;
    FILE *fw_vystup;
    do {
        printf("Zadejte D pro vypocet deflatoru HDP nebo T pro vypocet tempa rustu HDP: ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        vyprazdni_buffer();
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                deflator(0, &fw_vystup);    //for this function everything goes well
               // exit(0);
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                tempo_menu();
                vyprazdni_buffer();
              //  exit(0);
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                printf("Konec programu.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Neznama volba.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (c != 'k' && c != 'K');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Please post the full code example.

Comment: `exit(0)` terminates the program. In order to "get back to main", put a `return` statement in your function.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

So this is assuming you're put `return` in all the case statements because this is the behavior you want.

The problem with main not printing until you press some keys. Try using `fflush(stdout)` in your `main` function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    FILE *fw_vystup;
    do {
        printf("Zadejte D pro vypocet deflatoru HDP nebo T pro vypocet tempa rustu HDP: ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        vyprazdni_buffer();
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                deflator(0, &fw_vystup);    //for this function everything goes well
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                tempo_menu();
                vyprazdni_buffer();
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                printf("Konec programu.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Neznama volba.\n");
                break;
        }

        fflush(stdout);  // <--- right here.
    } while (c != 'k' && c != 'K');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, the return is doing it's job. (I just need it everywhere except the switch in main) but I have another problem... after returning you have to hit a button or two to get the printf from main function...

Comment: I edited the answer. It seems like there's a problem with clearing the stream buffer. You haven't provided the code for `vyprazdni_buffer()` so perhaps it causes the trouble?

Comment: void vyprazdni_buffer(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
}

Comment: Is it really needed? Could you comment out the body of this function and then run the program? Also, use fflush(stdout).

Comment: yes it is needed, without it, it printf "Neznama volba." (which means unknown choice) after every enter or so

Comment: You could try using fflush(std) in `vyprazdni_buffer` instead of the while loop with `getchar()`... Other than that, right now I have no better idea how to help right now... I'd search up on buffer clearing / printf problems.